Projective Representations with Linearly Independent Ranges?
I'm curious to know if given a (finite) group $G$ and a say an irreducible faithful projective representation $\pi: G \longrightarrow \text{GL}(V)/ \mathbb{C} I$ (for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$) if there is a name for the condition that the range $(\pi(x))_{x \in G}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\text{GL}(V)/ \mathbb{C} I$?
If this doesn't have a name, would there be a way to determining if such a thing exists for a group of small order?  In particular, I'm interesting in finding an irreducible faithful projective representation of the form $\pi: G \longrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})/ \mathbb{C}I$ where the range $(\pi(x))_{x \in G}$ is linearly independent set for $G$ nonabelian and $|G| = 16$.
So far, I have been assisted in finding the existence of a degree $4$ irreducible faithful projective representation of $\text{Smallgroup}(16,3) = \langle x,y,z \: | \: x^4=y^2=z^2=e, \: xy=yx, \: yz=zy, \: zx=xyz \rangle$ here (I need the degree to be atleast $4$ to even have a shot at my linear independence property holding at all).  However after computing the dimension of the span of the $16$ resulting unitaries in the range, I end up with dimension $13$, so it doesn't generate all of $M_4(\mathbb{C})$ unfortunately.
Is there anything I could try in an attempt to find such a specific representation with this linear independence property, or perhaps there's something I could try to prove no such representation for nonabelian groups of order 16 exists?
$\textbf{Note}:$ I have been able to show that any nonabelian metacyclic group of order $16$ can't admit such a representation, so the only possibilities left are the $4$ non-metacyclic nonabelian groups of order $16$.
Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.
